# How to run command in last focused terminal window using bash?

Tags: bash, gnome, gnome-terminal

How can I modify this function to open a new tab in the last focused terminal window, vs opening an entirely new terminal window?

```
# Opens a new terminal tab and runs the file.
run_in_terminal(){
    # $1=file_path
    msg="Running $1 
        in $qube_name Terminal..."
    # notify-send "$msg";echo "$msg"
    echo "$msg"

    sudo gnome-terminal --tab --active --geometry=120X60 \
    --title="$1" --working-directory="$code_directory" \
    -- bash -c "$1; exec bash"
}
```

Comment: I would be surprised if gnome-terminal opens a way to find out, which window was the most recent one, which got the focus, but in any case, such a question seems to be more suitable for [su] than Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm scripting it.  It's very much in the wheelhouse of stackoverflow ip.

Comment: If not the last terminal window, would it be possible to just grab the first terminal window found in a list of open windows and use that, then make then focus that window?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps [this](https://people.gnome.org/~ebassi/docs/_build/Gtk/4.0/method.Window.set_focus.html) would work, if you use C. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095553/invoking-gnome-activities-overview-from-command-line) too could be helpful, if you want to avoid C.

Comment: Similar to your requirement: https://askubuntu.com/questions/641683/how-can-i-send-commands-to-specific-terminal-windows.

Comment: How would you run this, if not from a terminal? Then by definition that is your latest focused terminal.

Comment: I'm looking to run it in the last focused terminal, not start a new terminal window like the script is doing now.  If there was no last focused terminal window, then yes, start a new terminal window.